# 400 Bad Request in Enterprise org

Tags: deployment, apexrest, error-messages

We have created an application on Salesforce.

This application has three components 
1. Salesforce cloud, 2. Unified Gateway server and 3. Mobile client for Android

To perform end-to-end testing, we have created Enterprise and Developer organization in Environment hub.

We have also created a Managed-Beta package and installed it for both organizations.

When we are trying to fetch data from Enterprise edition Org using REST API request call, we are getting HTTP error "400 Bad request".

But while executing the same application flow on Developer org, we are able to fetch data with HTTP status "200 Status OK".

Can you please help us to identify root cause of this behavior?

Comment: it's difficult to understand what can be actual cause, Can you provide your REST API request code for the both instances.

Comment: there is no change in the code of any of the instance. we have created a package and installed on two different type of org one is Dev and other one is Enterprise

Comment: 400 bad request is typically for the incorrect request data, What kind of data you are fetching? and what kind of your request data look like, is it JSON or xml?

Comment: We are fetching Opportunity data and data is in JSON format

Comment: Are you using Salesforce standard sobject API or you have written any custom webservice API for that?

Comment: we have created our web-service, in that we have check whether user have permissions to access for the Salesforce Standard sObject APIs.